# All software center mirrors are not working?

Tags: software-center, update-manager, mirrors

When I try to update using update manager I get :

> Requires installation of untrusted packages   The action would require
>   the installation of packages from not authenticated sources.

When I try to install any thing via software center I get the same error but this time with an option of `repair`

> Failed to download repository information Check your Internet
>   connection.

I looked for some solutions for this problem and one of them was to change the mirrors (servers) but when I try to change by choosing a specific server nothing happens ,the problem still there.

And when I choose: `select best server` I get :

> No suitable download server was found  Please check your Internet
>   connection.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved it by disabling the proxy.

Go to *System Settings*, then *Network*, *Network proxy* and on *method* chose *None*.